# How to select where my overflow ellipsis starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a list-view of some forumtopics, with the number of posts inside. At the moment I have a static example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLw7f1wg/).

This is how I trigger the ellipsis:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

ul li {
    line-height: 3em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And the HTML structure:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>21:26</span>
        <a>Klaagcorner</a>
        <span>
            <a>29703</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
       ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the `25.9K` jumps to the next line, because the title is so long. Is there a way to select where the ellipsis has to start? Putting `width: ##px` doesn't do anything on the `a`-tag. Maybe it works when putting the ellipsis on another element?

I tried to add the styling to trigger the ellipsis on an element down (so instead of `ul` on `ul li`, and instead of `ul li` on `ul li a`), but this didn't seem to do the trick. Both pure CSS and JS/jQuery-solutions are welcome!

**How it looks now:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting the ellipsis on the entire `<li>` instead of just the `<a>`

Move the ellipsis code to look like this:

```
ul li {
    line-height: 3em;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

ul li > a{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/aLw7f1wg/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was already suspecting I put the `ellipsis`-part on the wrong thing, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox), it's pretty simple.

First, take the overflow stuff off of the `ul` and the container `li`. We don't need that; it applies to stuff that overflows the entire `ul` and the `li`, respectively.

We make the `.posttitel` element the container, which it already is:

```
.posttitel {
    border-top: 2px solid #bbb;
    display: flex;  /* make it a flex container */
    flex-flow: row nowrap;  /* ask it not to wrap, and to orient along a row */
    justify-content: space-between;  /* space out the items along the row, allocating extra space between each item */
}
```

Then we tell it to give any extra space to the actual post title, which really needs it's own class:

```
.posttitel > a:nth-child(2) {  /* this should get a class, like .titel */
    flex: 1;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

We'll add a bit of margin to the `.date`:

```
.date {
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

And we're done!

I've made a JSBin for it (http://jsbin.com/wacotu/edit?css,output) and embedded a snippet below.

```js
var comments = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.comments a'))
var commentsCount = comments.length

function kFormatter(num) {
    return num > 999 ? (num / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'k' : num
}

comments.forEach(function (comment) {
    comment.textContent = kFormatter(comment.textContent)
})
```

```css
#laatste-nieuws {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}

ul li {
 line-height: 3em;
 padding-left: 20px;
}


.posttitel {
 border-top: 2px solid #bbb;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.date {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.posttitel > a:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.comments {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="laatste-nieuws" class="list">
  <div class="tabtitel">
    <h4><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Laatste forumreacties</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="home-laatstenieuws-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="itemrow posttitel">
        <span class="date">21:26</span>
        <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=5050&forum_id=15&start=1486" title="Klaagcorner">Klaagcorner</a>
        <span class="comments">
          <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=5050&forum_id=15" title="Reacties op Klaagcorner">29703</a>
        </span>
      </li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">21:20</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=12769&forum_id=17&start=17" title="Black Ops 3 [Algemeen Topic]">Black Ops 3 [Algemeen Topic]</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=12769&forum_id=17" title="Reacties op Black Ops 3 [Algemeen Topic]">329</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">21:07</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=11652&forum_id=17&start=191" title="Destiny">Destiny</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=11652&forum_id=17" title="Reacties op Destiny">3805</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">21:07</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=11652&forum_id=17&start=191" title="Destiny">Destiny</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=11652&forum_id=17" title="Reacties op Destiny">3805</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">21:02</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=1399&forum_id=20&start=239" title="Wehkamp">Wehkamp</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=1399&forum_id=20" title="Reacties op Wehkamp">4767</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">20:42</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=681&forum_id=15&start=1297" title="Het waar doet het je aan denken spel! (5 posts wachten!)">Het waar doet het je aan denken spel! (5 posts wachten!)</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=681&forum_id=15" title="Reacties op Het waar doet het je aan denken spel! (5 posts wachten!)">25939</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">20:27</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=14454&forum_id=17&start=3" title="Guitar Hero Live vs Rockband 4">Guitar Hero Live vs Rockband 4</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=14454&forum_id=17" title="Reacties op Guitar Hero Live vs Rockband 4">54</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">20:16</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=6959&forum_id=15&start=752" title="Juichcorner">Juichcorner</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=6959&forum_id=15" title="Reacties op Juichcorner">15036</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">20:14</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=11640&forum_id=17&start=25" title="Tales of [Algemeen Topic]">Tales of [Algemeen Topic]</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=11640&forum_id=17" title="Reacties op Tales of [Algemeen Topic]">491</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow posttitel"><span class="date">19:57</span> <a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=1538&forum_id=17&start=169" title="Laatste hardware-aankoop">Laatste hardware-aankoop</a><span class="comments"><a href="/forum.php?page=topic&topic_id=1538&forum_id=17" title="Reacties op Laatste hardware-aankoop">3368</a></span></li>

      <li class="itemrow"> <a href="/index.php?page=laatsteforumreacties">Bekijk de laatste 100 forumreacties</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end #laatste-reacties -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I had access to the HTML, I would definitely go with your answer. Since that's not the case though (it's for a mockup to show to someone what we can do with CSS), but since it's nice (and up-to-date!), I gave you a +1 anyway :)